# What Should be in the Profiles and Editor Objects of the launchSettings.json File in .Net 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to learn Web API in .Net 5. I created a Web API project which automatically generated Get, Put, Post, Delete methods in the controller class. I removed Swagger from the Statup.cs as shown below so that I don't see it when I run the API in the browser in Dev environment.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddTransient<TemplateServices>();
  //services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
  //{
  //    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Editor", Version = "v1" });
  //});
}

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  //app.UseSwagger();
  //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Editor v1"));
  }
}
```

Then I remove references to Swagger in the Profiles and Editor objects in launchSettings.json file. I also changed my Get and Post methods in the Controller class from the default Get and Post methods to the following:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class GeneratorController : ControllerBase
{
 [HttpGet("GenerateData/{input}")]
 public string GenerateData(string input)
 {
 }

 [HttpPost("GenerateData/{input}")]
 public string GenerateData([FromBody] string input)
 {
 }
}
```

I would like to know why when I use https, I am getting the error "This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset." What must be inside of the launchUrl fields in the Profiles and Editor objects? I tried putting "api/value" into these fields like some posts online have suggested but it didn't work. I made sure to use port 5001 for requests using https and 5000 for http but that didn't work either. However, a controller method without an input param seems to work.

The following code is in my launchSettings.jsonfile:

```
{
   "$schema":"http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
   "iisSettings":{
      "windowsAuthentication":false,
      "anonymousAuthentication":true,
      "iisExpress":{
         "applicationUrl":"http://localhost:31816",
         "sslPort":44347
      }
   },
   "profiles":{
      "IIS Express":{
         "commandName":"IISExpress",
         "launchBrowser":true,
         "launchUrl":"api/value",
         "environmentVariables":{
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"Development"
         }
      },
      "Editor":{
         "commandName":"Project",
         "dotnetRunMessages":"true",
         "launchBrowser":true,
         "launchUrl":"api/value",
         "applicationUrl":"https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
         "environmentVariables":{
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"Development"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you generate the API project with Visual Studio, you can uncheck "Enable OpenAPI support" to disable swagger and check "Configure fo HTTPS" to enable HTTPS. It will generate the "launchSettings.json" and you can compare with your current project.

Comment: Can you show your "launchSettings.json"? Maybe somebody can detect the problem.

Comment: I have added the launchSettings.json file

Comment: It has two profiles, IIS Express and Editor. Which one do you use?

Comment: Both IIS Express and Editor are automatically generated in the launchSettings.json file. Editor is the name of my project. I looked at other projects and the code pretty much look the same in the launchSettings.json file; there is a profile and then there is the current project

Comment: How do you start your API? If is debug from Visual Studio, the start button show the chosen profile?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you came to the code you have provided.
Let me show what compiles and works for me

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class GeneratorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GenerateData/{input}")]
    public string GenerateData(string input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    [HttpPost("GenerateData/{input}")]
    public string GenerateDataPost([FromForm] string input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Additional calls in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   //...

   app.UseRouting();

   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}
```

And finally `launchUrl` based on what routes you have configured in controller

```
"launchUrl": "Generator/GenerateData/GenerateData/inputValue",
```

`Generator` - controller name (`[controller]` in Route attribute)
`GenerateData` - method name (`[action]` in Route attribute)
`GenerateData` - extra path in attribute (`GenerateData` in HttpGet attribute)
`inputValue` - everything else in the path (`/{input}` in HttpGet attribute)

Comment: I have modified my method attributes and launchURL based on the suggestions above but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I have modified also post method name and Startup as compared to your code.